# Google Analytics same property ID tracked twice

Tags: google-analytics

Considering the fact that I want both self domain traffic tracking as well traffic tracking across multiple domains, I would like to know if the following implementation is acceptable and if I can keep both GA scripts on a site.

On the contrary, if for some reason this implementation is faulty, I would like advice as to which of the two should be removed in order to avoid tracking the same property ID twice.

```
<script> (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o), m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m) })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga'); ga('create', UA-XXXXXXXX-Y', 'auto'); ga('send', 'pageview'); </script>


<script> var _gaq = _gaq || []; _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-Y']); _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]); _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'ironlawofmarket.com']); </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot track the same property ids with both Universal Analytics and asynchronous Google Analytics. You would have to look into your account if it's UA or "classical" Analytics and use the appropriate code (look into the property settings and there in the tracking code tab. Since you have UA tracking code in your example I assume that you have UA). It's an either - or decision.

(Or at least it should be - actually accounts that have been switched to Universal Analytics will for some time accept tracking calls from the old tracking code. However this would simply count everything double if used with the same property id).

Bottom line: You should never track to the same property id twice.

You can however use two different versions of the tracking code if they track to different property ids and if the accounts are configured for the respective versions of the code.